# c++ mouseover event

Tags: c++, visual-c++, position, onmouseover

ok s it is really easy to create mouse over event if the object is NOT moving.
but the problem that the object gonna be moving every 50 millisecond.
it is not a string line so i can create a script it is a circle.
i used to use getcursorpos().  than get the object x and y.
the other problem is this

```
 p  X---------------------

 y 
 |
 |     
 |
 |       cursor
 |
 |
 |
```

where it says p that is the position ill get for the x and y.
   where is the cursor in the middle if ill get the position of the cursor and compare it  to the x and y they won't match.
   plus the object keeps moving so it is harder to track.
   any idea?
   sorry if what i said is confusing i couldn't explain it better.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: win32 is that what you're asking about?

Comment: You are using plain Win32 for the GUI? What is the object you are tracking, custom drawn or some child-window? If you don't tell us what you are using its hard to give useful suggestions.

Comment: really sorry i forgot to minition it im using gdi to draw an eclipse than set a timer to move the eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390(VS.85).aspx) documentation it say:

> A pointer to a POINT structure that
>   receives the **screen coordinates** of the
>   cursor

But when you draw you have to provide client coordinates. Is this is the issue you will need to transform from screen coordinates to client coordinates with the function aptly named [ScreenToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952(VS.85).aspx).

But instead of tracking the cursor position by hand I suggest to use the [WM_MOUSEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645616(VS.85).aspx) event, which already provides you with the client coordinates.

Comment: +1 for the screen/client coordinates. but more thing need to be added if the mouse remain static and eclipse was moved onto the mouse.

Comment: @YeenFei you can use WM_MOUSEMOVE to track where the last position of the mouse is, and then use WM_TIMER to move the circle, you can add a check for the last cursor position is close the the circle. 

Windows uses an event based programming model, you have to design your programs in term of those events provided by the system (mouse move, mouse click, timer firing, button click, etc, etc).

Comment: your answer is not really helpfull you didn't give me detials.
can you give me more detials

Comment: If you read the documentation I've pointed you will see at the bottom a link to a sample application which does much of what you are looking for, here is the link in the case you have missed it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648380%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Using_the_Keyboard_to_Move_the_Cursor.